# What does "_exec_command_posix(status=-1) failed" mean?

Tags: python

I am running a astrophysical code in python, and keep on getting the following error. Also it points out to so many files for error, which I believe is propagation of error in one file to another due to dependencies. Can any one please let me know what the potential source of error could be, and what could be the potential resolution?

```
C compiler: g++ -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-

D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC

compile options: '-I/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/weave -I/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/weave/scxx -I/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/weave/blitz -I/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c'
extra options: '-O3 -fopenmp'
g++: /usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/weave/scxx/weave_imp.cpp
_exec_command_posix failed (status=-1)
[Errno 12] Cannot allocate memory: /bin/bash
[Errno 12] Cannot allocate memory: /bin/bash
<weave: compiling>
running build_ext
running build_src
build_src
building extension "sc_e981423f81bfbadbd406446759c03af41" sources
build_src: building npy-pkg config files
customize UnixCCompiler
customize UnixCCompiler using build_ext
customize UnixCCompiler
customize UnixCCompiler using build_ext
building 'sc_e981423f81bfbadbd406446759c03af41' extension
compiling C++ sources
C compiler: g++ -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC

compile options: '-I/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/weave -I/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/weave/scxx -I/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/weave/blitz -I/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c'
extra options: '-O3'
g++: /usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/weave/scxx/weave_imp.cpp
_exec_command_posix failed (status=-1)
[Errno 12] Cannot allocate memory: /bin/bash
[Errno 12] Cannot allocate memory: /bin/bash
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "example2_NSE.py", line 71, in <module>
    mag = fit.Get_flux_theoretical(par, phout)
  File "/home/djonl/Documents/CAUS/CAUS_B_github/CAUS_IS/Photometry/Photometry.py", line 1026, in Get_flux_theoretical
    self.Make_surface(par, verbose=verbose)
  File "/home/djonl/Documents/CAUS/CAUS_B_github/CAUS_IS/Photometry/Photometry.py", line 255, in Make_surface
    offset_mag_d = par['offset_mag_d']
  File "/home/djonl/Documents/CAUS/CAUS_B_github/CAUS_IS/Core/Star_base.py", line 744, in Make_surface
    self._Calc_teff()
  File "/home/djonl/Documents/CAUS/CAUS_B_github/CAUS_IS/Core/Star_base.py", line 201, in _Calc_teff
    irr_pwr_prompt = self.cd._Calc_Prompt_Radiation(self)
  File "/home/djonl/Documents/CAUS/CAUS_B_github/CAUS_IS/Core/IBS_base.py", line 748, in _Calc_Prompt_Radiation
    self.emission_sky = self._Calc_sky_teff(star, -np.copy(self.norm_vecs_cd_shift),self.std_dev_cd, cd_pwr_prompt, do_eclipse = True) # -norm_vecs_cd points in the emission direction
  File "/home/djonl/Documents/CAUS/CAUS_B_github/CAUS_IS/Core/IBS_base.py", line 553, in _Calc_sky_teff
    gauss_weights_sky = self._Star_Eclipse_Sky(star, gauss_weights_sky)
  File "/home/djonl/Documents/CAUS/CAUS_B_github/CAUS_IS/Core/IBS_base.py", line 640, in _Star_Eclipse_Sky
    get_flux = scipy.weave.inline(code, ['gauss_weights_sky', 'low_bounds', 'upp_bounds',  'n_faces_cd', 'n_faces'], type_converters=scipy.weave.converters.blitz, compiler='gcc', extra_compile_args=['-O3'], extra_link_args=['-O3'], headers=['<cmath>'], libraries=['m'], verbose=2)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/weave/inline_tools.py", line 366, in inline
    **kw)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/weave/inline_tools.py", line 496, in compile_function
    verbose=verbose, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/weave/ext_tools.py", line 373, in compile
    verbose=verbose, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/weave/build_tools.py", line 279, in build_extension
    setup(name=module_name, ext_modules=[ext],verbose=verb)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/distutils/core.py", line 169, in setup
    return old_setup(**new_attr)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/distutils/core.py", line 169, in setup
    raise SystemExit, "error: " + str(msg)
scipy.weave.build_tools.CompileError: error: Command "g++ -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC -I/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/weave -I/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/weave/scxx -I/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/weave/blitz -I/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c /usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/weave/scxx/weave_imp.cpp -o /tmp/scipy-dkandel-ZzPySL/python27_intermediate/compiler_d7bc7dd909091493221604a37a5db4b5/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/weave/scxx/weave_imp.o -O3" 
failed with exit status 999
```

**Edit:**
When I run `ulimit -a` I get the following output:

```
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 30970
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1024
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 1024
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

Comment: `[Errno 12] Cannot allocate memory: /bin/bash`

Comment: include the output of `ulimit -a`

Comment: @fferri Sorry, what do you mean by "include the output 'ulimit -a' "?

Comment: Run `ulimit -a` at the shell (to determine if your account is configured to have memory or process contraints). Add its output to your question. Wouldn't also hurt to actually check available virtual memory. C++ compilers sometimes can be quite memory hungry, *especially* with high optimization levels. How many processes you're allowed to start may also be a pertinent issue, &c.

Comment: (on which point, this isn't quite a pure Python question, inasmuch as it's invoking a C++ compiler to build a native extension where the issue actually takes place).

Comment: @fferri @Charles Duffy I have updated my question with the output of `ulimit -a`.

Comment: ...okay, so not likely to be a per-user limit; the size available to be locked to physical memory is low, but none of that should be needed here. How much free RAM is available at the time when this happens? (Referring to virtual memory, so available swap space counts).

Comment: ...if we knew whether the issue was the `fork()` or the `execve()` failing, that would be guidance on whether to look at the limit on per-user process count as well (only pertinent for the former).